# Attendance Sheet in Google Sheets Using forms

Tags: excel, google-sheets, time, time-and-attendance

This is a pseudo code for my excel work

`IF sheet1(column(range)).value IS Exit in sheet2(column(range)).value  on specific(date) in sheet2(column(range)).value(date) Then print "P"  Else print "A"`

Hello guys i create a google form for employee attendance so i want that when employee submit their form and automatic update in daily attendance sheet in google sheet.
but i don't find any solution regarding this issue and i need to create like in images [Daily Attendance Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJsjv.png)

Comment: please share a minimal reproducible example, it will be easier to help you in your locale

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.